# open single activity from appwidgetprovider without using singleinstance or singletask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm writing an app in which I have several activities, e.g. Activities A->B->C->D.  In addition to that we can launch activities from an app-widget.

The app requirements:

- `Activity C` can be launched from an `AppWidgetProvider` and should show the home screen when either back or home are pressed.
- The app should start from `Activity A` whenever the application is launched (e.g. if the user is pressed home button while on `Activity D`, relaunching the app should start from `Activity A`.)

The current approach followed:

The `singleInstance` / `singleTask` modes are used so as to clear activity stack to satisfy requirement.  However, `onActivityResult()`, `android:activityOpenEnterAnimation`, `android:activityOpenExitAnimation`, `android:activityCloseEnterAnimation`, `android:activityCloseExitAnimation,` etc., are not working when using these modes.

Is there any alternative to achieve the requirements?

Comment: are u familiar with intent? if not than use it

Comment: what flags should I use with intent

Comment: Just for clarification: If the user is using the app and is in any of the activities (A, B, C, or D) and presses the HOME button, you want that when he returns to the app it will start Activity A again? You realize that isn't the normal behaviour and it may confuse your users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Activity Lifecycle tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) on the Android Developers site would be a good place to start.  It includes a [complete example](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip) of exactly how lifecycles are handled

Comment: Starting application from "activity A" not a major requirement. Following use case is failing . when user is in Activity B (A->B), then "Activity A" and "Activity B" will be in stack. when user press home button and now launches "Activity C" from widget, pressing back showing "Activity B" and the "Activity A" which is unwanted.

Comment: I'm npot sure about this but try to use .finish() before u start the intent which goes from B to C (B->C). then your activities will die so they wont come when u press back button